# Logged in twice on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, gnome, login

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What does it mean when I appear twice in the output given by ‘finger’, on Ubuntu 9.04](https://superuser.com/questions/50935/what-does-it-mean-when-i-appear-twice-in-the-output-given-by-finger-on-ubuntu)

Since recently, when I log into my Ubuntu desktop (9.04) with Gnome set up and then log out, I get a popup that states that still someone is logged in and that I need to enter the admin (sudo) password to continue the shutdown.

When I use the `users` command in the console I see:

```
# users
pan69 pan69
```

I seem to be logged in twice. Why is this?

**UPDATE:**

For some reason the problem disappeared just as mysteriously as it appeared. I did run an update late Friday evening that installed some OS related updates but I'm not entirely sure this had anything to do with it.

Comment: Duplicate: http://superuser.com/questions/50935/what-does-it-mean-when-i-appear-twice-in-the-output-given-by-finger-on-ubuntu

Comment: The question you are referring to doesn't answer my question at all. That user is simply logged in through multiple TTY's, I'm not. I login and when I log out immediately I'm presented with a sudo popup that requires the admin password stating that some other use is still logged in (but I'm the only one). I would appreciated it if you would reopen my question so I can find a answer to this issue.

Comment: actually, that user is logged in on one tty (tty7, eg X-windows) and one pseudo-tty (pts/0, probably via his gnome-terminal window).  if you would like this reopened, edit your question with the output of `finger` or `who` so we can see that this really is a separate issue.

Comment: I know I'm logged in twice. The answer to the other question verifies that. However the answer doesn't explain WHY this happens and how I get rid of it. This issue started a week ago. I've been running my current set up for almost a year now, why is this issue suddenly happing now?

Comment: Luke, we'd still need more info.  the `users` output doesn't tell us anything; any answer would be pure speculation.  the output of `who` will give some real details and might help find a solution.